# laravel using jQuery Ajax | Ajax Cart

Tags: laravel

I'm Trying to Save The Product into The Database By Clicking On Add To Cart
But It's Not Adding I Also Use Ajax `

### I Want To Add The Cart To DataBase And It's Not Adding.

This is The Error That I cant Add Any Product To The Cart Because Of It

```
message: "Call to undefined method App\User\Cart::where()", exception: "Error",…
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ChOR.png)

Model Page.

```
    class Cart extends Model
{
use HasFactory; I
protected $table = 'carts';
protected $fillable = [
'user_id',
'prod_id',               
'prod_qty',
];
}
```

Controller page.

```
  public function addToCart(Request $request)
{
    $product_qty = $request->input('product_qty');
    $product_id = $request->input ('product_id');
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        $prod_check = Product::where('id',$product_id)->first();

        if($prod_check)
        {                
            if(Cart::where('prod_id',$product_id)->where('user_id',Auth::id())->exists())
            {
                return response()->json(['status' => $prod_check->pname." Already Added to cart"]);
            }
            else
            {
                $cartItem - new Cart();
                $cartItem->user_id = Auth::id();
                $cartItem->prod_qty = $product_qty;
                $cartItem->save();
                return response()->json(['status' => $prod_check->pname." Added to cart"]);
                
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['status' => "Login to Continue"]);
    }
}
```

javascript page.
This Is MY First Time To Use Ajax And Sure That Every Thing Is Correct I Want Know Why Its Not Add

```
$('.addToCartBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val();
    var product_qty = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.qty-input').val();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/add-to-cart",
        data: {
            'product_id': product_id,
            'product_qty': product_qty,
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
        }
    });
    // alert(product_id);
    // alert(product_qty);
    // // alert ("test ") ;
});
```

Route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
Route::post('/add-to-cart', [App\Http\Controllers\User\indexController::class, 'addToCart' ]);});
```

So why this error occurs, how can I fix it?`

Answer (score 0):

This look like an error in importation like App\Models\Cart not like this?

verify if you had added `use App\Models\Cart;`

Comment: Bro Thank You Very Much I Forgot to Add The File